# Definition of vector field along a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $γ : I→R^3$ be a regular parametrization of a curve *C*. If asked what a vector field on *C* is I would perhaps answer like this:

1) "a smooth function $v$ associating to any point $γ(t)$ of *C* an element of the tangent space of $R^3$ at $γ(t)$".

An alternative answer: 2) "a smooth function $f$ associating to any *t* $∈$ *I* an element of the tangent space of $R^3$ at $γ(t)$".

My question: is the second answer technically wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In fact, I'd prefer the second definition - it's what Lee uses in his *Riemannian Manifolds* book:

> [image]

This allows a curve to intersect itself at a point in different directions while being able to record this fact in the velocity vector. I think if one takes seriously the idea that "curve" refers to the map $\gamma:I\to M$, and not its image $\gamma(I)\subset M$, then this is the right definition.

However, I'd say your first definition is appropriate if you're talking about vector fields on the subset $\gamma(I)$, having forgotten about $\gamma$. From Lee's *Smooth Manifolds* book:

> [image]

Comment: The point about self intersections is a nice one!

Comment: Good answer. It really depends on whether you're thinking of "a curve" as a _parametrized curve_ (i.e. a function from an interval into some space) or as a set of points (typically the image of some parametrized curve). To work with "vector fields along curves," it's usually most useful to work with the former interpretation, in which case the OP's second definition is the right one.

Comment: @Jack Lee : And we use the differential structure of the tangent bundle of the manifold to determine smoothness of the assignment?

Comment: @MSIS: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @JackLee: Prof Lee, if I may please ignore otherwise. I'm trying to gain a better understanding of Covariant Differentiation. Is it the case that the Derivative Vector Field of a circle with the parametrization $(Cost, Sint)$ given by $(-Sint, Cost)$ is a Tangent Vector Field so that $(Cost, Sint)$ is the actual Covariant Derivative, since there are no non-tangential components to it? And the normal vector  field N is never-tangent, so that it projects to the 0 vector on each tangent space, so that its Covariant Derivative is identically 0?

Comment: @Jack Lee: If you prefer, I can write this as an actual question here, to make it easier, I hope, for you to answer. Hope I,m not too lost :). Can you think of a vector field on the circle whose derivative has non zero components of each?

Comment: @MSIS: Yes, you should ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Here it is, if you're available: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371042/examples-of-covariant-differentiation. I hope I am not too lost :)