# Vector fields (on a manifold) and terminology

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I read in several books (Do Carmo, **Riemannian Geometry** or John M. Lee, **Smooth manifolds**) that a *vector field* $X$ on a smooth manifold $M$ is a mapping which associates to each point $p \in M$ a tangent vector $X(p) \in \mathrm{T}_{p}M$. With a more general point of view, a vector field is a section of the tangent bundle $TM$.

Given a differentiable curve $c : I \subset \mathbb{R} \to M$, the derivative $\dot{c}$ of the curve is sometimes called *velocity field*. However, I fail to see how $\dot{c}$ is a vector field of $M$. What am I missing ?

Comment: It's not a vector fields on $M$. It's a vector field along a curve. See the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294327/definition-of-vector-field-along-a-curve)

Comment: There is a nice expository answer that might help you [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88880/an-easy-way-to-to-explain-the-equivalence-definitions-of-tangent-spaces).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The velocity field $\dot{c}$ is not a vector field on the manifold, but it is a section of the pullback of the tangent bundle by $c$, usually denoted by $c^*TM$. This basically means that it is a "vector field defined on the image of $c$" (and then, not really, as it could have more than one value at a point of the image, if $c$ crosses itself).