# Examples of Covariant Differentiation

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

I am trying to gain a better feel for Covariant Differentiation.

I am thinking of the circle , parametrized as $ C(t):=(\cos t, \sin t) ; 0\leq t \leq 2\pi)$.

Is it correct to say that it's derivative vector field $C'(t)$ , given by $ 
C'(t):=(-\sin t, \cos t)$, is purely

Tangential, in that , for each $t_0$, $(\cos t, \sin t)$ lives in the tangent space at $(\cos t_0, \sin t_0)$?

I know that an informal way to test for it being tangent is that it's perpendicular to the normal

through  the segment$(0, t_0)$. Is this rigorous?

Is it accurate too, to say the Normal vector field assigning a normal vector at each point, has

no tangential component, so that it projects to $0$ in the tangent space, and it's covariant derivative is thus $0$? ( The 0 vector).

Can anyone provide an example of a vector field $X$ ; on the circle or otherwise, whose

derivative has both Tangential and Non-Tangential components?

EDIT: I am aware of one way of doing this decomposition: Say the circle is

embedded in $\mathbb R^2 $. Then we do a vector-space decomposition of

$\mathbb R^2$, as $T_p S^1 + N $ , with N normal to the circle, and express tangent vectors accordingly.

EDIT: I realized some careless issues here:

1. We  differentiate tangent vector fields along a curve. (Cost, Sint); at least as I am using it, is not a vector field, but the chosen parametrization of the curve. Since the derivative vector field (-Sint, Cost) is indeed a tangent vector field, it can be differentiated. We find the standard Euclidean derivative , assuming the vectors are vectors in the tangent space to $\mathbb R^3 $ and project the results to $T_p S^1$ at each point.
2. The normal vector field N(x,y)=(x,y) is not a tangent vector field in the unit circle.

Thank you

Comment: What is covariant differentiation to you? Do you have a definition?

Comment: Not fully formal, but we use a connection to allow for the fact that, unlike with $\mathbb R^n $ tangent spaces at different points are not naturally-isomorphic to each other, so that the standard differential quotient makes no sense. We choose a collection of isomorphisms to connect/map the tangent space ( as a vector space) at a point p, with the tangent space at a point q. All this leads to the Christoffel symbols. The derivative will be a vector field, but may not fully live in the tangent space. So the Covariant Derivative is the projection of the Derivative V. Field into the Tangent Spac

Comment: Issue is that the derivative as a vector field ( as with any other vector field) may not live in the tangent space, so that we project it down to the tangent space, and this is the Covariant derivative.

Comment: Do you know what is the covariant differentiation of a normal vector fields?

Comment: To grasp covariant differentiation you should begin with the standard covariant derivative of $\mathbb R^n$, this is a generalization of the directional derivative where one calculates how, for two vector fields, the 1st varies in the direction of the 2nd, that leads you to do $D_FG=[JG]F$ where one can see how the components of $G$ varies in the direction of $F$

Comment: The derivative of vector field $(-t sint,t cost)$ will have both tangential and normal components

Comment: @ArcticChar: AFAIK, you can only find the Covariant Derivative for Tangent Vector Fields.